# MIUI how to request permissions?

Tags: android, android-permissions

It seems like MIUI implemented own permission model before Android 6.
The problem is that for my app it is needed to request all permissions at start of Main Activity.
In Android 6 it's easy for me.

Is there a way to do the same for MIUI?

`ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission` returns that every permissions is granted.